# Is there a way to automatically create a plural route for index and singular for everything else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes

When dealing with a collection resource, I like to use the plural for the index (ie. list) page (viewing many *objects*), and singular for the other pages (create/update/delete one *object*).

In order to do so, I seem to have to create my routes like so:

```
map.objects 'objects.:format', :controller => :object, :action => :index, :conditions => { :method => :get }
map.resources :object, :controller => :object, :except => :index
```

This creates routes like so:

```
     objects GET    /objects(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"object"}
object_index POST   /object(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"object"}
  new_object GET    /object/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"object"}
 edit_object GET    /object/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"object"}
      object GET    /object/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"object"}
             PUT    /object/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"object"}
             DELETE /object/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"object"}
```

It works, but it seems like I'm using an extra line in my routes file (to explicitly specify the index route) when I shouldn't have to. Is there a way to do what I want in one route? Or, alternately, is there a reason not to route this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTful routing is designed in such a way that you're scoping down what it is you want to do. Say you go to `http://example.com/objects`. Here, you're telling the site you want a list objects.

Now when you go to `http://example.com/objects/2` you're telling it you want to see the object with identifier of 2 in that list (or resource) of objects.

Finally, when you go to `http://example.com/objects/2/edit` you're saying you want to find the object again with identifier of 2 but this time you would like to edit it rather than view it.

By going against the grain like you have suggested in routing helpers you will be causing a tremendous amount of unnecessary pain for yourself and for anybody else reading your code.

However if you do choose to go this path (again, I advise against it) then yes, defining two routes is the only way.

Comment: @Ryan, I do understand how RESTful routing works, but I disagree that it'll cause pain to have the URLs make a little more sense (in an English perspective), beyond having the extra line in the routes file as you mentioned. From a user's perspective, who doesn't know or care about REST, it might be a little clearer that `/objects` is a list page, while `/object/2` refers to the object with ID 2 (whether or not using a numeric ID is user-friendly is a different story)

Comment: @Daniel: if you think that users cared that much about URLs, then why does ebay have such terrible ones, but is still successful? You're honestly spending too much time thinking about a problem that nobody will notice / care about.

Comment: @Ryan I agree with Daniel here, I think URL crafting is very important for power users and for the ability for users to guess how your system is setup. SEO as well factors in here.

Comment: @Jesse: With all due respect, I think my users are smart enough to be able to read my URLs and discover that they are pluralized words and adapt easily. Even SO has pluralized "resources", so why differ from the mainstream for such little gain?

Comment: @Ryan -- I'm saying I like SO's structure, and that URL structure is important... If you agree, then we're on the same page. I would not do /objects and /object/23

Comment: @Ryan that's a fair point, I *am* probably overthinking things here. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason other than "normal REST says don't" to not have the "object" be a resource under "objects" is search engines.

Google will notice that you have "recipes" and then recipes under "recipes", and give you those cool sitelinks:

[image: sitelinks]

> Google's Webmaster Guidelines say, in
>   the first item under design and
>   content guidelines, "Make a site with
>   a clear hierarchy and text links."